# Use window object in angular2 but vscode "Cannot find name 'window' "

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I wrote an `angular2` app in Visual studio code. Recently, I updated Visual Studio Code to 1.10.2. But it has highlighted `window` as having an error. When I checked it, I found that it says:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'window'.

My code is as follows:

```
saveCustomIndex(customIndex:any,indexName:string){
    window.localStorage.setItem(indexName,JSON.stringify(customIndex));
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Problem screenshot]

How can I deal with this? Thank you!

Comment: Try to add options  `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],` in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On `tsconfig.json`, make sure to have `"dom"` on your list of libraries.

`tsconfig.json` should be looking more or less like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: it's exist, but i still have this error message everytime I try to build (ng build) : "Cannot find name '$window'. Did you mean 'Window'?"