# TypeScript Cannot find name 'window'

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor

In my Meteor/React project I have the following line:

`let gameId = window.prompt("Please enter the ID of the game you wish to load.");`

TypeScript gives the transpiling error `Cannot find name 'window'`.
I am using [barbatus/typescript](https://github.com/barbatus/typescript), with default compiler options:

`{
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "sourceMap": true
}`

I tried creating a tsconfig.json in the root of my Meteor project, copying the above compiler options but appending the line:

`"lib": ["es2015",
    "dom"]`

However, the error remains.

Comment: Please add your `tsconfig.json` to your question, even if it's in the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use window object in angular2 but vscode "Cannot find name 'window' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745178/use-window-object-in-angular2-but-vscode-cannot-find-name-window)

Comment: Your `tsconfig.json` must have "dom"

Comment: can you try after adding "declare var window: any;"  in you code

Comment: are you sure you add `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json as `compilerOptions` property,not the root json.

Comment: Adding `declare var window: any;` works!
@holi-java You are right I left that out. The solution described in my question now also works, although doing that now means I get App.js and App.map.js files being generated (from App.tsx) whenever Meteor recompiles.

Answer (score 2):

I added "dom" to the lib compilerOptions in tsconfig.json，then this problem has been resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30639817)